# C# Amazon S3 Upload file with progressbar

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I have one class function for upload a file to S3:

```
    public void UploadFile(string filePath, UploadProgress uploadProgress)
    {
        TransferUtilityUploadRequest uploadRequest;
        TransferUtility fileTransferUtility;

        try
        {
            mClient = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);

            uploadRequest =
                new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
                {
                    BucketName = BUCKETNAME,
                    FilePath = filePath
                };

            uploadRequest.UploadProgressEvent += new EventHandler<UploadProgressArgs>(uploadProgress);

            fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(mClient);
            fileTransferUtility.Upload(uploadRequest);
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Exception)
        {
            throw s3Exception;
        }
    }
```

From the form class, I have a function for update the progressbar:

```
    private void UploadFile_ProgressBar(object sender, UploadProgressArgs e)
    {
        int pctProgress = (int)(e.TransferredBytes * 100 / e.TotalBytes);
        progressBarUpload.Value = pctProgress;
        progressBarUpload.Invalidate();

        Console.WriteLine(e.TransferredBytes + " / " + e.TotalBytes + Environment.NewLine);            
    }
```

And the call to upload file is:

```
    mS3.UploadFile(fileToUpload, UploadFile_ProgressBar);
```

The console show the progress but the progressbar no works. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are creating a Windows Form application with your progressbar.
So, check this out:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar

Also, I saw you are using the .Invalidate Method of Progressbar. As documentation says, this method does force a synchronous paint, without the Update method. Try it out.

> Calling the Invalidate method does not force a synchronous paint; to force a synchronous paint, call the Update method after calling the Invalidate method. When this method is called with no parameters, the entire client area is added to the update region.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a(v=vs.100).aspx

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is That You Can not access member of System.Windows.Forms.Control from different thread than UI thread will cause cross-thread exception.
There is only one thread (UI thread), that is allowed to access System.Windows.Forms.Control and its subclasses members.

**To Solve This You have to use the Invoke Method like this:**

```js
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
    this.progressBarUpload.Value = pctProgress;
}));
```